# Talend Automation Job taking too much time

Tags: talend

I had developed a Job in `Talend` and built the job and automated to run the Windows Batch file from the below build

[image]

On the Execution of the **Job Start** Windows Batch file it will invoke the **dimtableinsert** job and then after it finishes it will invoke **fact_dim_combine** it is taking just minutes to run in the **Talend Open Studio** but when I invoke the batch file via the Task Scheduler it is taking hours for the process to finish

**Time Taken
Manual -- 5 Minutes
Automation -- 4 hours (on invoking Windows batch file)**

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this Automation Process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the delay in the execution would be a latency issue. Talend might be installed in the same server where database instance is installed. And so whenever you execute the job in Talend, it will complete as expected. But the scheduler might be installed in the other server, when you call the job through scheduler, it would take some time to insert the data.

1. Make sure you scheduler and database instance is on the same server
2. Execute the job directly in the windows terminal and check if you have same issue

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know what is taking so much time is to add some logs to your job.

First, add some tWarn at the start and finish of each of the subjobs (dimtableinsert and fact_dim_combine) to know which one is the longest.

Then add more logs before/after the components inside the jobs.

This way you should have a better idea of what is responsible for the slowdown (DB access, writing of some files, etc ...)